# Query not utilising index on Many to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select V.VisitID
from Visit V
inner join VisitDrug VD on V.VisitID = VD.VisitID
inner join Lookup.Drug D on VD.DrugID = D.DrugID
where V.StartDate >='2019-03-27 13:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
and V.StartDate <='2020-03-31 12:59:59.9990000 +00:00'
```

What I don't understand is whenever a join operation is done on VisitDrug, it has to do a full-scan of all the rows in the table, rather than only those applicable VisitIDs.

The indexes currently are:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VisitDrug] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_VisitDrug] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VisitID] ASC,
    [DrugID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VisitDrug_DrugID_VisitID] ON [dbo].[VisitDrug]
(
    [DrugID] ASC,
    [VisitID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and the Execution Plan is - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy6QLqT8I

From reading other questions, I believe the indexes are correct, but not being used.

Comment: Looks fine to me. No columns from `Lookup.Drug` are used, so it gets factored out, then it seeks on `[dbo].[Visit].[nci_wi_Visit_C3450B8BB360D53175200CF38BC2F596]` to find matching rows based on DateCreated (I guess StartDate is a computed column on that), then sorts by `VisitID` so it can merge join with `[dbo].[Visit].[nci_wi_Visit_C3450B8BB360D53175200CF38BC2F596]`. Were you expecting something different?

Answer (score 1):

Because this query requires a large number of visits, the optimizer decided it would be cheapter to read the date range on the index on Visit.StartDate, then sort the resulting Visits and then MERGE JOIN with VisitDrug.  The alternative is to perform 49,914 seperate index seeks on the PK_VisitDrug, for a total of 150,000-200,000 Logical IOs.

You can test the other plan by specifying a [LOOP JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible indexing strategies which could be used here, and your current index covers none of the possibilities.  Here is one option:

```
CREATE INDEX v_index ON Visit (StartDate, VisitID);
CREATE INDEX vd_index ON VisitDrug (VisitID, DrugID);
CREATE INDEX l_index ON (DrugID);
```

If used, the above three indices would speed up the query.  The first `v_index` takes advantage of the `WHERE` clause restriction on `StartDate`.  Then, the `vd_index` speeds up the join, as does the `l_index`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the second date comparison:

```
select V.VisitID
from Visit V inner join
     VisitDrug VD
     on V.VisitID = VD.VisitID inner join
     Lookup.Drug D 
     on VD.DrugID = D.DrugID
where V.StartDate >= '2019-03-27 13:00:00.0000000 +00:00' and
      V.StartDate <  '2020-03-31 13:00:00.0000000 +00:00' 
------------------^ note the change here
```

Then for this query, the optimal indexes are:

- `Visit(StartDate, VisitId)`
- `VisitDrug(VisitId, DrugId)` (which you already have)
- `Drug(DrugId)`  (which you probably already have)